# How does one go about growing a cactus in a terrarium?

Tags: cactus, container-gardening

I've been searching the web online, and the ideas are all conflicting. Some websites would say cacti are unable to grow in glass jars because the heat trapped will cook the cactus, and other websites say that it is possible to grow cacti in glass jars as long as the soil composition and drainage is right.

With that being said, how does one go about growing a cactus in a terrarium, assuming that it can be grown in one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, maybe you could also explain why you'd prefer a terrarium.

- A Cactus can easily be happy out of the terrarium in a room, there is no need for a terrarium, Terrarium gets hot and humid exactly opposite what a cactus is used to
- They are used to hot and dry lands, and their fleshy organs will fail in humid or cold weathers, bacteria and diseases will kill them in such situations.

So, if you still need to grow one in a terrarium:

1. Be sure it doesn't get sultry, proper air conditioning, with different holes up and down the terrarium so that cool air comes from bottom and hot air moves out from top holes.
2. you need to be very careful about watering the cactus, if it receives water and gets only a little warm, it's gonna get swollen and get a bad shape or even die.
3. A bigger terrarium, would be easier to control
4. And I don't know if it's possible for you or not, but I saw a guy who had hooked up an [arduino](http://arduino.cc/) with some sensors and fans to control the humidity and temperature of his terrarium, well since a cactus is very sensitive in a terrarium, maybe you could use one like that as a big help.

Comment: my house is too small for a garden- so i thought it'd be great to have a mini garden(terrarium), unless there are better alternatives?

Comment: also my problem now, I recommend using tropical plants who love terrariums, or gather around some great cactus in your room together with some light and create a nice landscape

Comment: you could start by something like this: `http://www.thegardenerseden.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/cactus-bowl-on-console.jpg`

Comment: Would this mean some cacti are more suitable for terrarium environments?

Comment: I meant other plants!

Comment: aww but I want to grow cacti- oh well

Comment: @Nick Jungle cacti would love a terrarium. They aren't your typical looking cacti, though.